# SQL ORDER BY for two conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've tried to resolve this problem more than two hours. I need your help. I want to sort data from two tables by using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT INV.`id` , INV.`userid` , Cli.firstname, Cli.lastname,   Cli.companyname, Cli.currency, INV.`total` , INV.`date` , INV.`duedate`
FROM tblinvoices AS INV, tblclients Cli
WHERE now( ) >= DATE_ADD( INV.duedate, INTERVAL +2
DAY )
AND INV.STATUS = 'unpaid'
AND Cli.id = INV.userid
AND INV.total >=200
AND INV.`date` != INV.`duedate`
) AS X
ORDER BY X.duedate ASC
```

I get this result :

```
id  userid firstname    lastname    companyname     currency    total   date    duedate 
3   3   younes  Abakarim        1   154877.00   2014-10-18  2014-11-01
9   12  Faissal Marouan 1   2568.00     2014-10-23  2014-11-06
34  3   younes  Abakarim        1   252.60  2015-01-10  2015-01-15
31  12  Faissal Marouan 1   288.00  2015-01-01  2015-01-15
36  3   younes  Abakarim    Bestgallery 1   288.00  2015-01-16  2015-01-19
```

But what I want is this:

```
id  userid  firstname   lastname    companyname     currency    total   date    duedate 
3   3   younes  Abakarim        1   154877.00   2014-10-18  2014-11-01
34  3   younes  Abakarim        1   252.60  2015-01-10  2015-01-15
36  3   younes  Abakarim    Bestgallery 1   288.00  2015-01-16  2015-01-19
9   12  Faissal Marouan 1   2568.00     2014-10-23  2014-11-06
31  12  Faissal Marouan 1   288.00  2015-01-01  2015-01-15
```

And still sorted by `duedate`.

Comment: -1 The dataset you say you want is not sorted by duedate, which is why the query does not return results in your desired order when you sort it by duedate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should fix your query so it uses proper `join` syntax and is a bit readable:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT INV.`id` , INV.`userid` , Cli.firstname, Cli.lastname, 
             Cli.companyname, Cli.currency,
             INV.`total` , INV.`date` , INV.`duedate`
      FROM tblinvoices INV JOIN
           tblclients Cli
           ON Cli.id = INV.userid
      WHERE NOW() >= DATE_ADD(INV.duedate, INTERVAL + 2 DAY) AND
            INV.STATUS = 'unpaid' AND
            INV.total >= 200 AND
            INV.`date` <> INV.`duedate`
     ) ic
ORDER BY Xic.duedate ASC;
```

Next, to get what you want is a bit complicated.  You want the same due date for each client.  That requires joining it in.  This would be much simpler if MySQL supported CTEs, but alas:

```
SELECT ic.*
FROM (SELECT INV.`id` , INV.`userid` , Cli.firstname, Cli.lastname, 
             Cli.companyname, Cli.currency,
             INV.`total` , INV.`date` , INV.`duedate`
      FROM tblinvoices INV JOIN
           tblclients Cli
           ON Cli.id = INV.userid
      WHERE NOW() >= DATE_ADD(INV.duedate, INTERVAL + 2 DAY) AND
            INV.STATUS = 'unpaid' AND
            INV.total >= 200 AND
            INV.`date` <> INV.`duedate`
     ) ic JOIN
     (SELECT INV.`userid`, MAX(INV.`duedate`) as maxdd
      FROM tblinvoices INV
      WHERE NOW() >= DATE_ADD(INV.duedate, INTERVAL + 2 DAY) AND
            INV.STATUS = 'unpaid' AND
            INV.total >= 200 AND
            INV.`date` <> INV.`duedate`
      GROUP BY INV.`userid`
     ) ud
     ON ic.userid = ud.userid
ORDER BY ud.maxdd ASC, ic.userid;
```

I'm not sure if you want the max or the min of the due date for the sorting.  The two are equivalent for your example.

Answer (score 0):

Add the second sort attribut with comma:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT INV.`id` , INV.`userid` , Cli.firstname, Cli.lastname,   Cli.companyname, Cli.currency, INV.`total` , INV.`date` , INV.`duedate`
FROM tblinvoices AS INV, tblclients Cli
WHERE now( ) >= DATE_ADD( INV.duedate, INTERVAL +2
DAY )
AND INV.STATUS = 'unpaid'
AND Cli.id = INV.userid
AND INV.total >=200
AND INV.`date` != INV.`duedate`
) AS X
ORDER BY X.userid ASC, x.duedate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT INV.`id`
    ,INV.`userid`
    ,Cli.firstname
    ,Cli.lastname
    ,Cli.companyname
    ,Cli.currency
    ,INV.`total`
    ,INV.`date`
    ,INV.`duedate`
FROM tblinvoices AS INV
    ,tblclients Cli
WHERE now() >= DATE_ADD(INV.duedate, INTERVAL + 2 DAY)
    AND INV.STATUS = 'unpaid'
    AND Cli.id = INV.userid
    AND INV.total >= 200
    AND INV.`date` != INV.`duedate`
) AS X
ORDER BY x.userid ASC
,X.duedate ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - adding a group by clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT INV.`id` , INV.`userid` , Max(Cli.firstname) firstname, Max(Cli.lastname) lastname,  Max(Cli.companyname) companyname, Max(Cli.currency) currency, Max(INV.`total`) total , Max(INV.`date`) date , Max(INV.`duedate`) duedate
FROM tblinvoices AS INV, tblclients Cli
WHERE now( ) >= DATE_ADD( INV.duedate, INTERVAL +2
DAY )
AND INV.STATUS = 'unpaid'
AND Cli.id = INV.userid
AND INV.total >=200
AND INV.`date` != INV.`duedate`
group by INV.userid, INV.id) AS X
ORDER BY X.duedate ASC
```